# Display the elements of the array one by one in a column js

Tags: javascript

I have an application where the user selects the words he will save. I write all these words into an array. I need to display each element of this array in a column so that when hovering over you could see the information (or by clicking)
I tried to iterate over each element of the array using `for` and `foreach` but only the last element was displayed
How can I arrange array elements in a column?

Array:

```
let a = ["First word","Second word","Third word"]
```

An example of what I need:

- First word
- Second word
- Third word

Need to display it on the page through `textContent` or `innerHTML` or something like that.

Comment: Please add the code you use to loop through the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is initializing a list and the adding dynamically all items to that list.

```js
const words = ["First word","Second word","Third word"]

const list = document.getElementById('myList')

words.forEach(word => {
  const item = document.createElement('li')
  item.textContent = word // or item.innerHTML
  list.appendChild(item)
})
```

```html
<ul id="myList"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solution using `for in`:

```js
let a = ["First word","Second word","Third word"],
  $list = document.querySelector('#list')

for(let i in a) {
  $list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li>${a[i]}</li>`)
}
```

```html
<ol id="list">List of items
</ol>
```